# Image auto width in CSS for all browsers?

Tags: css

I have my `img` tag defined with some CSS as:

```
img
{
  width: auto !important;
  height: auto !important;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

It works just fine in some of the Mobile Browsers I have tried, as well as Google Chrome on a desktop. However, it does not seem to work in IE or FireFox. By that, I mean, as you resize the window. Take a look at a sandbox site I am working on:  http://terraninstitute.com. I have the image on the home page intentionally set to be a huge picture. Also navigate to the Information (main menu) then Newcomers (side menu) and notice the map image at the bottom.  On my Droid (and a few other devices I can get my hands on) as well as in Google Chrome this looks pretty good. In IE and FireFox, not so much.

Am I missing something? Conflicting style definitions? I am not finding them as of yet if it is.

TIA

Comment: Why not just set width to 100%?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're declaring the width of your images multiple times in your document unnecessarily and declaring a max-width the wrong way. `Max-width` is supposed to define a max size/boundary for your images (600px, for example), if you declare **max-width:100%** in conjunction with **width:100%**, you're not really doing anything with that declaration as the images will expand 100% as it is.

Remove the width declarations from your CSS in the following lines:

line 116: delete the `img` declaration all together, it is not needed.

line 365: remove the `max-width:100%` and `height:auto;` attribute as they are not needed (and if you can delete the declaration all together as you can declare that elsewhere)

line 121: Now just stick with this one and just add the following:

```
img {
   height: auto;
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks.  I cleaned up all of the img tags in the various CSS files leaving the one in the inuit.css file.  It was interesting playing with width vs max-width and you were right.  width was all I needed.  So many wrong turns when I googled for it.  And inuit.css was setup for CSS3 and auto scaling so I just *assumed* it should always work.  When I first started it did work (I thought).  Further in now and adding too many CSS definitions and finally things started going south.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap) solution for responsive images:

```
img {
  /* Responsive images (ensure images don't scale beyond their parents) */

  /* Part 1: Set a maxium relative to the parent */
  max-width: 100%;

  /* IE7-8 need help adjusting responsive images */
  width: auto\9;

  /* Part 2: Scale the height according to the width, otherwise you get stretching */
  height: auto;

  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `!important`

Make your CSS more speficic:

```
body img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: To whoever downvoted Diodeus: he wasn't suggesting this as a solution.  He was pointed out a good CSS practice.

Answer (score 1):

in style.css line line 116, 212 and in inuit.css line 365. Remove all those.

```
img{
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Thats all you need.